# Jquery / Javascript - get list of request URLs for that session like in browser console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to be able to retrieve the list of request URLs that are displayed in the browser console, i.e: `GET  http://mydomain.com/index.php?p=1&curr=GBP&cat=Food.   200`. Users can click around my app and apply different filters and scrolls through pages and I need some way of tracking this so that I always know what data has already been loaded for that users session.

I had thought about using PHPs `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and saving them in a session but then I don't know how I would access this session from my JQuery as its JQuery that constructs the URLs.

Has anyone any idea how I can access this data from the console?  Is this possible?  If not can anyone suggest a workaround?

The PHP / JQuery mess I have so far:

```
<?php
    session_start();                   
    //keep track of requests.
    if (!isset($_SESSION['requests'])) {
        $_SESSION['requests'] = array();
    } else {
        if (!in_array( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SESSION['requests'])) { 
            $_SESSION['requests'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
    }
    $requests = json_encode($_SESSION['requests']);

    print_r($_SESSION['requests']);
    print_r($requests);  //these both have values
?>

//further down the page is the javascript
$('.filter a').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
    //***more code for filtering etc******/

    var paginate_url = $('.paginate a').attr('href');

    //THIS IS PART I CANNOT GET WORKING
    var visited_urls= <?=$requests?>;
    //console.log($.parseJSON(visited_urls));

    console.log(visited_urls); //is always empty
    var pageno = '';  //somehow check to see if the URL that has been clicked exists int he requests array, if so get the page number and increment.

    var next_url = UpdateQueryString(paginate_url, pageno, group, encodeURIComponent(filter_qry));
```

Comment: In my own understanding of your problem, you may probably need to use [Cookies](http://php.net/setcookie) or [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage) since you want to access some data through browser level which is in jQuery

Comment: As per my understanding you just need to cache ajax data to save your server request. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

This is my suggestion:

**PHP + Javascript Implementation:**

1. In PHP, use $_GET['curr'] and `$_GET['cat']` to retrieve the arguements from the URL.
2. Use `$_SESSION['curr'] = $_GET['curr'];` to save them per the session.
3. On your Javascript/jQuery use `var curr = "<?php echo $_SESSION['curr']; ?>"` to make the PHP session variables available to your Javascript.

Basically the key to have a good PHP/Javascript persistent memory is that you can set PHP content into a Javascript variable by using:

```
var x = <?php echo '123';?>;
console.log(x); //output '123' to Javascript console
```

If you need to have a list of all visited urls, you can save them in a PHP array and transfer it to Javascript as well.

On PHP side:

```
  if (!isset($_SESSION['visited'])) $_SESSION['visited'] = array();//initialize the array if doesn't exist

  if (!inarray( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SESSION['visited']) { //check if current URL is not in array
     $_SESSION['visited'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//push it to the array
  }
```

On Client side:

```
 //this will convert the PHP array to a Javascript array using json_encode
  var visited_urls= <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['visited']); ?>;
```

- Don't forget to use session_start() on every page you need the session variables.

**Javascript Only Implementation:**

Use localStorage and keep everything on the client side.

**EDIT:** Note that localStorage is only supported in IE8 and up, so if versions prior to IE8 must be supported, you will need to use Cookies instead of localStorage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var urls = JSON.parse(localStorage["visited"]) || [];//get the visited urls from local storage or initialize the array

   if (urls.indexOf(document.URL) == -1) {//if current url does not exist in the array
    urls.push(document.URL);//add it to the array
    localStorage["visited"] = JSON.stringify(urls);//save a stringifyed version of the array to local storage
   }

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but Id need to check the session on the onclick event to see if the link that has been selected already exists in the session array.  if it does, I need to increment the page number of the one saved in the session.  I can't see how I can do this in PHP until after the link has been selected, by which its too late as the page has been rendered.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @LeeTee I've added more info in my answer that should help you resolve your question. Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes I think converting the session array to JSON is a good idea, however I get an empty value for console.log(visited_urls) but when I print out the session in PHP its not empty

Comment: @LeeTee are you using session_start() on the top of your page?

Comment: I have updated my code in the original query to show exactly what Im doing in the index.php page.  I only have the one page and have therefore only called the session_start(); once a the top of this page.

Comment: Why don't you try memcache? It's like a database you can access from both PHP and javaScript (a quick search gave me [this](http://www.wxjavascript.net/mc/index.html) result).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do but I think you can skip the PHP and just use JavaScript and sessionStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage or localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage (depending on how persistent you want the data to be)

For example if I want to listen for all clicks on 'a' tags and track whether those hrefs have been visited (and how many times)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // store an empty object in session storage when the page loads
    sessionStorage.visited = JSON.stringify({});
});

$('a').on('click', function() {
    var storage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.visited),
        href = $(this).attr('href');

    // when we get a click check to see if this has been clicked before
    if (!storage[href]) {
        // if not save it and set the count to 1
        storage[href] = 1;
    } else {
        // otherwise increment the count
        storage[href]++;
    }

    sessionStorage.visited = JSON.stringify(storage);
});
```

If you want to save the urls from your ajax calls the same principle applies but listen for the ajaxSuccess event and store the url from the request in the callback: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Comment: Yes ideally I would like to do it in JS as opposed to PHP.  I will give this a try. thanks

Comment: Any luck with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want to achieve with this feature. You state:

> Users can click around my app and apply different filters and scrolls through pages and I need some way of tracking this so that I always know what data has already been loaded for that users session.

What do you want to achieve with this, why isn't the browser's cache enough for you?
My idea for a solution would be to sync server session array with an object inside the Browser via some sort of WebSocket (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

---

**UPDATE2**:
It is possible to use localStorage as cache storage as Abel Melquiades Callejo suggests and then read from it bypassing HTTP requests. I would choose what content to save to that cache differently, no server involved:

- add a custom attribute data-* to every HTML element you want cached (http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/);
- make a querySelectorAll (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) for all HTML elements with that attribute;
- storing and retrieving documents from localStorage should be easy now, you need a convention for naming files for easy finding;
- storing images implies doing a base64 transformation which increases the size of the data by 34% (image with 64kb will take 86kb in localStorage).
- you need a way to find when data in localStorage is obsolete and you need to make requests to the server (perhaps another data-age attribute to specify when should it expire).

However, this localStorage solution is limited to a small amount of data, see this issue https://github.com/RemoteStorage/remoteStorage.js/issues/144. So, although I now see that what you are asking is possible, because of this size limitation to localStorage, I strongly recommend the solutions in my UPDATE1, below.

---

**UPDATE1**: The point is that caching mechanisms are incredibly complex. A better alternative would be to use the default browser caching mechanisms:

#### 1. HTML5 cache manifest

- Go offline with application cache
  http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/
- LET’S TAKE THIS OFFLINE http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html
- Using the application cache
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache
- A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

#### 2. Server's response headers to HTTP requests

- Optimize caching - Leverage browser caching
  https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching
- HTTP Caching FAQ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_Caching_FAQ

Comment: "Why isn't the browser's cache enough for you?" what makes you think it isnt? it would be an option if I knew how!?

Comment: Well, try my latest suggestions, sorry if my earlier remarks came out as offensive.